# Firebase query with Vue js

Tags: firebase, vue.js, firebase-realtime-database

i am new in Vue JS and in Firebase. My target is get all 'eventos' that has same category. I mean, let's i have two eventos, an eventos category "SMIX" and another has "DAM". Now i want to get the eventos has category 'SMIX'

My data structure is here :
[image]

```
 created() {
            var datos = []

            firebase.database().ref('usuarios').on("value", data => {

                data.forEach(function(user){
                    user.child("eventos").orderByChild("categoria").equalTo("SMIX")
                        .forEach(function(evento){
                        datos.push(evento.val())
                    });
                });

                this.eventos = datos;
            });
        }[My data Structure][1]
```

Comment: what do you get from the request?

Comment: @EduardoLeite i get this error user.child(...).orderByChild is not a function

Comment: why don't you do your request with orderbychild an equalTo? you would not get this problem and the response would be smaller

Comment: I didn't get you. Could provide an example please?

Comment: Hi, i did that you said  user.child("eventos").ref.orderByChild("categoria").equalTo("SMIX")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several errors and points to be noted in your code:

**Firstly,** if you receive the error `user.child(...).orderByChild is not a function`
it is because with `data.forEach(function(user) {...})`, `user` is a `DataSnapshot` (see the [`forEach()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.DataSnapshot#foreach) doc), and by calling the [`child()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.DataSnapshot#child) method on this `DataSnapshot` you get another `DataSnapshot`... which does not have a `orderByChild()` method.

The `orderByChild()` method is a method of a [`Reference`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference), so you need to do

```
user.child(...).ref.orderByChild()
```

using the [`ref`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.DataSnapshot#ref) property of the `DataSnapshot`

---

**Secondly**, you cannot do

```
user.ref.child("eventos").orderByChild("categoria").equalTo("SMIX")
                        .forEach()
```

because you need to use the `once()` or `on()` methods to get the data at a database location represented by a `Reference`.

---

**Thirdly**, Since you are going to execute several queries within a loop, you need to use the [`once()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference#once) method instead of the [`on()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference#on) method. The `on()` method set a listener that continuously "listens for data changes at a particular location."

---

**Finally**, note that you need to use [`Promise.all()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) to manage the parallel asynchronous queries to the database.

---

So, having noted all the points above, the following code will do the trick (to put in `created()`):

```
        var datos = []

        firebase.database().ref('usuarios').once('value')
        .then(dataSnapshot => {
            var promises = [];
            dataSnapshot.forEach(user => {    
                promises.push(user.ref.child("eventos").orderByChild("categoria").equalTo("SMIX").once('value'));
            });
            return Promise.all(promises);
        })
        .then(results => {
            //console.log(results);
            results.forEach(dataSnapshot => {
                dataSnapshot.forEach(evento => {
                    datos.push(evento.val());
                });     
            });
            this.eventos = datos;
        });
```